# Speed up Eclipse CDT start up?

Tags: java, c++, eclipse-plugin, ide, eclipse-cdt

it takes loads of time for eclipse CDT to start!
in order to test a simple .cpp file we need to wait for minutes to actually start coding.
any tips to speed up it's start?
i have disabled all plugins at start up and i'm using java 7.1 and eclipse juno.
i tried to configure the eclipse.ini file which lead to crash many times.

Comment: #1  This is way to broad of a question.  Put more details into it.  Also you might want to put what version of eclipse, what processor speed, ram and so on.

Comment: Two tips: 1) Buy an SSD 2) Buy a better processor

Comment: Another note:  If you're using any sort of anti-virus that scans archives every time they are opened, eclipse can be very slow to start up, as each of it's plugins is its own JAR file.

Comment: @MarkBasler i tried the solutions present on eclipse forms which included changing eclipse.ini but it leads to crash...i am using java 7.1 with eclispe juno. Eclipse CDT for c/++ development

Comment: @DaveS yes i think it is because of McAfee antivirus.When i disabled it , it caused a boost in start up time. Is there a way to exclude eclipse from McAfee??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer about configuring the ecilpse.ini file can help you:

[What are the best JVM settings for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse)

The configuration I have has increased a bit the overal performance, but at the cost of slightly slower startup

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-nosplash
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-server
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xss1m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1g
-Xverify:none
-XX:CompileThreshold=2500
```

Answer (score 0):

I think since Eclipse is written in Java and relies on the JVM, you might want to look at where your JVM in installed (in addition to looking where Eclipse itself is installed). Maybe you have a slow disk. I like having my development tools on a SSD, but that is an expensive option.